# How to convert a recursive function into a tail-recursive version?

Tags: scala, recursion

I have a function that I can't seem to make tail recursive.

I've tried creating helper functions with extra accumulators but either the algorithm does not produce the expected results or it really is not tail recursive.

This are the functions:

```
    def game(boardState: BoardState,
             pieces: List[ChessPiece],
             acc: Set[BoardState]): Set[BoardState] = pieces match {
      case Nil => acc + boardState // No more pieces, boardState solved
      case x :: xs => getStates(boardState, x, xs, acc)
    }

    def getStates(boardState: BoardState,
                  piece: ChessPiece,
                  rest: List[ChessPiece],
                  acc: Set[BoardState]): Set[BoardState] = {
      // Ask if there are available squares
      if (boardState.availableSquares.nonEmpty) {
          // Get the states from every available square
        boardState.availableSquares.foldLeft(Set[BoardState]())((innerAcc, sqr) => {
          // Get the next chess piece
          val nextPiece = buildPiece(piece, sqr)
          // Check if placing the piece would result in an existing piece being attacked
          if (boardState.withPieces.forall(sqr => !nextPiece.isAttacking(sqr))) {
            // Do the recursion with the new Board State
            val newState = boardState.placePiece(nextPiece)
            innerAcc ++ game(newState, rest, acc) //This is the part that is not tail recursive
          } else innerAcc
        })
      } else {
      // There are no available places, search ends here
        acc
      }
    }
```

Thanks in advance for your advice!

Comment: Can you share your code, which compiles? I mean can you share also BoardState, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hmm, `game()` calls `getStates()` and `getStates()` calls `game()`. This looks like something that a trampoline would handle.

Here's an attempt using [TailCalls from the Standard Library](https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/api/current/scala/util/control/TailCalls$.html).

```
import scala.util.control.TailCalls._

def game(boardState: BoardState,
         pieces: List[ChessPiece],
         acc: Set[BoardState]): TailRec[Set[BoardState]] = pieces match {
  case Nil => done(acc + boardState) // No more pieces, boardState solved
  case x :: xs => tailcall(getStates(boardState, x, xs, acc))
}

def getStates(boardState: BoardState,
              piece: ChessPiece,
              rest: List[ChessPiece],
              acc: Set[BoardState]): TailRec[Set[BoardState]] = done{
  // Ask if there are available squares
  if (boardState.availableSquares.nonEmpty) {
    // Get the states from every available square
    boardState.availableSquares.foldLeft(Set[BoardState]())((innerAcc, sqr) => {
      // Get the next chess piece
      val nextPiece = buildPiece(piece, sqr)
      // Check if placing the piece would result in an existing piece being attacked
      if (boardState.withPieces.forall(sqr => !nextPiece.isAttacking(sqr))) {
        // Do the recursion with the new Board State
        val newState = boardState.placePiece(nextPiece)
        innerAcc ++ tailcall(game(newState, rest, acc)).result
      } else innerAcc
    })
  } else {
    // There are no available places, search ends here
    acc
  }
}
```

Warning: I got this to compile after dummying all the missing pieces (`BoardState`, `ChessPiece`, etc.), so I haven't actually tried to *run* it. Next time please post enough code to make it a [minimal, complete, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: This worked as expected and required the less modification to the code. Very cool, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

Scala tail recursion optimisation requires three things:

1. The function must be self-recursive
2. The function must call itself only once for each call
3. The self call must be in the tail position

In order to satisfy 1. you need fold the implementation of `game` into `getStates`.

Satisfying 2. is harder because of that `foldLeft` call which may cause multiple recursive calls. The solution to this is to pass the `availableSquares` list to the recursive function and process one element in each call. This is the trickiest thing to do.

To satisfy 3. you will need to make the final result a parameter to the call and the return that result when there is no more work to be done. When you do the recursive call you add the new data to the result and pass that down with the other parameters.

This is only an outline of the solution, but I hope it helps.

Comment: 4. It must be `final`

Comment: I have an update, but now I don't know if it's recursive at all? :(

Comment: @JörgWMittag If it is method, yes it must be `final`, but I don't personally use recursive methods, I always embed the recursive function inside an outer method.